# what is the difference between filtering on accumulator/current in reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming, reduce

When chaining the `Array.prototype.reduce` with `Array.prototype.filter` what is the difference (conceptually and under the hood) when filtering on the current value instead of the accumulator value?

```
// function union creates a union of all values that appear among arrays
// example A

const union = (...arrays) => {
    return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const newElements = acc.filter(el => !curr.includes(el));

      return curr.concat(newElements);
    });
  };
 console.log(union([1, 10, 15, 20], [5, 88, 1, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5]));

// output (7) [1, 10, 15, 5, 88, 7, 20]

// example B

const union = (...arrays) => {
    return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const newElements = curr.filter(el => !acc.includes(el));

      return acc.concat(newElements);
    });
  }; 
  console.log(union([1, 10, 15, 20], [5, 88, 1, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5]));

//output (7) [1, 10, 15, 20, 5, 88, 7]
```

The difference in output would suggest that the order in which the arrays are being evaluated is 'opposite'. As far as I can tell when using `arr.filter` the values are evaluated from end to beginning with the opposite being true for `curr.filter` . Besides from that are they any other consequences dependent on if you filter through the accumulator or current value? Could this throw an error in a different context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't about the use of `filter` inside of `reduce`, so much as it is about the order in which you're using `acc` and `curr`.

When I'm running into seemingly strange inconsistencies like this, the first step I usually take is to create a test case and run through it manually. Here, you've already created a test case for us...

```js
const testData = [
  [1, 10, 15, 20],
  [5, 88, 1, 7],
  [1, 10, 15, 5],
]
```

Now we need to run through each version of the function and see what the output is at each stage.

One thing to note (which I didn't know until this evening!) is that if `reduce` doesn't receive an `initialValue` as the second argument, it will use the first item in the array as the `initialValue`. This means we only need to consider 2 executions of each function instead of 3.

### Example A

```js
const union = (...arrays) => {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const newElements = acc.filter(el => !curr.includes(el))

    return curr.concat(newElements)
  })
}
```

In the first version of the function, the short description of what's happening is that we're looping over the accumulator (`acc`) and removing all items that already exist in the array that we're currently comparing (`curr`). Then we add that list to the *end* of `curr`.

The fact that we’re pushing `newElements` onto the end of `curr` is important. This is why the order is different for the 2 different versions.

#### First execution

```js
const acc = [1, 10, 15, 20]
const curr = [5, 88, 1, 7]
const newElements = [10, 15, 20] // these elements exist in acc but not in curr
curr.concat(newElements) === [5, 88, 1, 7, 10, 15, 20]
```

#### Second execution

```js
const acc = [5, 88, 1, 7, 10, 15, 20] // carried over from first execution
const curr = [1, 10, 15, 5]
const newElements = [88, 7, 20] // these elements exist in acc but not in curr
curr.concat(newElements) === [1, 10, 15, 5, 88, 7, 20]
```

### Example B

```js
const union = (...arrays) => {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const newElements = curr.filter(el => !acc.includes(el))

    return acc.concat(newElements)
  })
}
```

In the first version of the function, the short description of what's happening is that we're looping over the array that we’re currently comparing (`curr`) and removing all items that already exist in the accumulator (`acc`). Then we add that list to the end of `acc`.

You can already see at the end of the first execution below that the results are turning out in a much different order.

#### First execution

```js
const acc = [1, 10, 15, 20]
const curr = [5, 88, 1, 7]
const newElements = [5, 88, 7] // these elements exist in curr but not in acc
acc.concat(newElements) === [1, 10, 15, 20, 5, 88, 7]
```

#### Second execution

```js
const acc = [1, 10, 15, 20, 5, 88, 7] // carried over from first execution
const curr = [1, 10, 15, 5]
const newElements = [] // these elements exist in acc but not in curr
acc.concat(newElements) === [1, 10, 15, 20, 5, 88, 7]
```

### Conclusion

The short answer to your question is that the difference between filtering on the accumulator and the current array is that the results are going to be different so long as the inputs are different. ‍♂️

> Besides from that are they any other consequences dependent on if you filter through the accumulator or current value? Could this throw an error in a different context?

Fortunately, there’s not any concern about errors. It is notable, however, that the second version of your function is [~10% faster](https://jsperf.com/union-accumulator-current-value-order) than the first version. I’d guess that this is purely circumstantial. A different test data set may produce different performance results.

Answer (score 0):

In example `1`, by the time you concat the two lists, you make sure that the `acc`umulator won't contain any element from `curr`ent.

In example `2`, on the other hand, you make sure that `curr`ent won't contain any element that is already present in `acc`umulator.

**The difference is on the final order in which the elements will appear**

---

I think both examples are not efficient since they both involve `O(n2)` time complexity, since you are nesting iterations. The second one, as stated by others, might be a little more performant since the nested iterations would be made on a chunk that is presumably shorter than the accumulator.

---

I'd rather write more or less like this:

```js
const union = (...tuples) => Array.from(
  new Set(
    tuples.flatMap(n => n),
  )
);



console.log(
  union([1, 10, 15, 20], [5, 88, 1, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5]),
);
```